# Magento 1.9.x.x version Run on PHP 7.x

Tags: php, magento

I have recently installed XAMPP with PHP version 7.x. After installation, i have configured my magento store of version 1.9.x and it show the following error.

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Function name must be a string in
>   app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php:555

Any one suggest me the solution to resolve it.

Comment: Get yourself in touch with the Inchoo Magento 1.9.x.x/PHP7 project. You have a lot of ground to cover and as you find issues, you can help them out in exchange for them broadly covering what they already found. http://inchoo.net/magento/its-alive/ and https://github.com/Inchoo/Inchoo_PHP7

Comment: Also, more pertinent thread over in magento.stackexchange.com => https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/74008/is-magento-ready-for-php-7/95687#95687

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Magento 1.x is not fully compatible with PHP 7.

This specific bug can be fixed, by overriding Mage_Core_Model_Layout and change line 555 from:

> $out .= $this->getBlock($callback[0])->$callback1;

to

> $out .= $this->getBlock($callback[0])->{$callback[1](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/105550/how-can-solve-error-magento-1-xx-on-php-7)}();

[Please Refer this link for more Information:](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/105550/how-can-solve-error-magento-1-xx-on-php-7)